# For /L loop with padded number

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, range

I wish to make a nested for loop in order to process some files. I have looked extensively for the solution, and have found many similar versions, but since this is my first time I am having trouble combining methods to do what I want.

Basically - I want a FOR /L loop that cycles through a range of padded numbers from 001 to say 500.

I know I can specify a range (1,1,500), but obviously not as (001,001,500). How can I add the 00, and then subsequently when %%a is >9, just a 0? I imagine this is as a sting but perhaps there is another way?

My code as I wished it to be (obviously wrong):

```
@echo off
for %%a in (001,001,500) do (
echo %%a
for %%s in (control scenario) do (
echo %%s
svic_ensemble.exe 28009_Trent_at_Colwick.cal Trent_%%s_%%a.txt 28009_Trent_at_Colwick.txt     Trent_%%s_%%a.out
)
)
pause
```

Many thanks

Ed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String processing in windows batch files: How to pad value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398545/string-processing-in-windows-batch-files-how-to-pad-value-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc my question is older - so you should have put the duplicate tag on the other question

Comment: [The general rule is to keep the question with the best collection of answers, and close the other one as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/230282), time is irrelevant here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can solve it with string manipulations.
First prefix the number with two zeros and then take only the last three characters.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%n in (1 1 500) do (
  set "num=00%%n"
  set "num=!num:~-3!"
  echo !num!
)
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way of getting zero-padding is to pad with plenty of zeroes and then use a substring:

```
set Number=1
set PaddedNumber=000000%Number%
set PaddedNumber=%PaddedNumber:~-3%
```

You can adapt this for use in the loop, although you'll need delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%a in (1, 1, 500) do (
  set num=000%%a
  set num=!num:~-3!
  for %%s in (control scenario) do (
    svic_ensemble.exe 28009_Trent_at_Colwick.cal Trent_%%s_!num!.txt 28009_Trent_at_Colwick.txt     Trent_%%s_!num!.out
  )
)
```