# String processing in windows batch files: How to pad value with leading zeros?

Tags: windows, batch-file

in a Windows cmd batch file (.bat), how do i pad a numeric value, so that a given value in the range 0..99 gets transformed to a string in the range "00" to "99". I.e. I'd like to having leading zeros for values lower than 10.

Comment: Rob van der Woude [lists several different methods](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_leadingzero.php) of both adding and removing leading-zeros along with their pros and cons.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a two-stage process you can use:

```
REM initial setup
SET X=5

REM pad with your desired width - 1 leading zeroes
SET PADDED=0%X%

REM slice off any zeroes you don't need -- BEWARE, this can truncate the value
REM the 2 at the end is the number of desired digits
SET PADDED=%PADDED:~-2%
```

Now `PADDED` holds the padded value. If there's any chance that the initial value of `X` might have more than 2 digits, you need to check that you didn't accidentally truncate it:

```
REM did we truncate the value by mistake? if so, undo the damage
SET /A VERIFY=1%X% - 1%PADDED%
IF NOT "%VERIFY%"=="0" SET PADDED=%X%

REM finally update the value of X
SET X=%PADDED%
```

**Important note:**

This solution creates or overwrites the variables `PADDED` and `VERIFY`. Any script that sets the values of variables which are not meant to be persisted after it terminates should be put inside `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL` statements to prevent these changes from being visible from the outside world.

Comment: There are two problems with this answer. 1) You should never use TEMP as a variable name. It is reserved to point to where temp files are stored. Overriding the value could break code elsewhere. 2) Your test for truncation breaks if the leading digit of your original number is a 9 or 8 because SET /A treats numbers prefixed with zero as hexadecimal, and 08 and 09 result in an error because they are invalid hex notation.

Comment: @dbenham: "Obviously" this is not a fully encapsulated solution, and like any code that sets environment variables it would have to be placed inside `SETLOCAL`/`ENDLOCAL`. Do you feel this should be spelled out? Regarding the zero prefix, I didn't know -- will investigate.

Comment: @dbenham: After some thought it seems to me that prefixing both numbers with `1` before subtracting will do the trick. Crude but effective.

Comment: @dbenham: ...and added a warning regarding `SETLOCAL`. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: As dbenham said, it's a bad idea to use "temp", even with setlocal this gets nasty if your batch stops at a syntax error, the endlocal will not be executed

Comment: Good idea with the 1 prefix. Regarding the variable name, certainly you can localize the value, but later code within the same context could still be broken. Why tempt fate? It is trivial to use a variable name that is not reserved by the system.

Comment: @jeb: That's definitely true. Edited again, the initial name choices were made in a flash and (I agree) were certainly not ideal.

Comment: An issue: `SET /A VERIFY=1%X% - 1%PADDED%` when X=`34` and PADDED=`034` is that `VERIFY` is now negative, and not zero.  So the next line `IF NOT "%VERIFY%"=="0" SET PADDED=%X%` throws away the new proper padded value and uses the old non padded value. :(

Answer (score 23):

If you are confident that the number of digits in your original number is always <= 2, then

```
set "x=0%x%"
set "x=%x:~-2%"
```

If the number may exceed 2 digits, and you want to pad to 2 digits, but not truncate values larger then 99, then

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%x%" equ "%x:~-2%" (
  set "x=0%x%"
  set "x=!x:~-2!"
)
```

Or without delayed expansion, using an intermediate variable

```
set paddedX=0%x%
if "%x%" equ "%x:~-2%" set "x=%paddedX:~-2%"
```

The nice thing about the above algorithms is it is trivial to extend the padding to any arbitrary width. For example, to pad to width 10, simply prepend with 9 zeros and preserve the last 10 characters

```
set "x=000000000%x%"
set "x=%x:~-10%"
```

TO prevent truncating

```
set paddedX=000000000%x%
if "%x%" equ "%x:~-10%" set "x=%paddedX:~-10%"
```

Comment: If you want, you can put the `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` inside hte if block, so it doesn't change unless you need it to.

Answer (score 8):

The single line

```
IF 1%Foo% LSS 100 SET Foo=0%Foo%
```

will get you what you want for numbers in the range that you specify. It does not change values in the subset 0-9 if they are already single-padded.

Comment: A simple loop would zero-pad to an arbitrary number of digits. Nice and short.

Answer (score 5):

Previous answers had explained all the existent methods to pad a value with left zeros; I just want to add a small trick I used to do that in an easier way. What had not been enough mentioned in previous answers is that in most cases, *the value that will be padded is incremented inside a loop* and that the padded value *is just used to display it* (or similar tasks, like renames). For example, to show values from 00 to 99:

```
set x=0
:loop
   rem Pad x value, store it in padded
   set padded=0%x%
   set padded=%padded:~-2%
   rem Show padded value
   echo %padded%
   set /A x+=1
if %x% leq 99 goto loop
```

If this is the case, the value of the variable may be used for both control the loop *and* display its padded value with no modification if its limits are appropriately translated. For example, to show values from 00 to 99:

```
set x=100
:loop
   rem Show padded value
   echo %x:~-2%
   set /A x+=1
if %x% leq 199 goto loop
```

This method works also with any number of left zeros to pad.

Antonio

Answer (score 3):

OK GUYS i have found a solution, compressing it down as simple as possible.

```
@echo off
title pad numbers
set num=0
set zero= 000
:loop
@set /a num=%num%+1
if /i %num% GTR 9 set zero= 00
if /i %num% GTR 99 set zero= 0
if /i %num% GTR 999 set zero= 
echo %zero%%num%
goto loop
```

this will display your count up number using 4 digits. but the code can be altered to use 2 digits as shown below.

```
@echo off
title pad numbers
set num=0
set zero= 0
:loop
@set /a num=%num%+1
if /i %num% GTR 9 set zero= 
echo %zero%%num%
goto loop
```

if you want to set it as a displayable single variable...

```
@echo off
title pad numbers
set num=0
set zero= 0
:loop
@set /a num=%num%+1
if /i %num% GTR 9 set zero= 
set %zero%%num%=number
echo %number%
goto loop
```

if you want it to count up in seconds...

```
@echo off
title pad numbers
set num=0
set zero= 0
:loop
@set /a num=%num%+1
if /i %num% GTR 9 set zero= 
set %zero%%num%=number
echo %number%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto loop
```

i hope this was a great help ^^

Answer (score 1):

This example uses a `for` loop to demonstrate, but the logic is the same even if you were to use it without the loop. Just `echo` a `0` in front if the number is less than 10.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%a in (1,1,40) do (
set n=%%a
if !n! lss 10 (
echo 0!n!
) else (
echo !n!
)
)
pause >nul
```

Comment: Actually it is not the same logic as Jon's answer. Your solution works fine if you only want to pad to 2 digits. But it becomes cumbersome as you pad additional zeros.

Comment: @dbenham The OP said `I'd like to having leading zeros for values lower than 10.` - so how would there ever be more than 2 digit's? I didn't mean to word it to compare it to Jon's answer, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ahh, I see now how I misinterpreted your language. True that the detail in the question specifies 2 digits, but the title is more general. And it is always nice to have a general solution if it is as simple as the special case.

Comment: Don't know why this isn't the actual answer, seems to accomplish the issue much quicker and simpler. I would just replace the ECHO and then SET the value, then ECHO or pass it to wherever.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
rem .
rem   counter example - with and without padding (up to 260 leading 0s which should be enough for most filenames)
rem .
rem   we assume values given are valid
rem   additional error checking could be done to make sure they are numbers
rem   and to ensure that starting is less than ending
rem   and that the number of ending digits is not greater than the number of padding digits
rem .
if "%2"=="" (
  echo.
  echo usage:   %~nx0 [starting number] [ending number] [pad]
  echo example: %~nx0  0  19        will output numbers 0 to 19 each on a new line
  echo example: %~nx0  3  12  8     will output numbers 3 to 12 each on a new line padded to 8 digits
  echo.
  goto end
  )
rem .
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%3"=="" (
  for /l %%x in (%1, 1, %2) do (
    echo.%%x
  )
) else (
  set "mynum="
  for /l %%x in (%1, 1, %2) do (
    call set "mynum=00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000%%x"
    call set "mynum=%%mynum:~-%3%%"
    call echo.%%mynum%%
  )
)
:end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier:

```
set build_b=00%your_value%
set padded_value=%build_b:~-2%
```