# How to output the numbers 0 to 350 always with three digits?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, iteration

How can I carry out this intended task in batch file?

The resulting `echo` of `%%h` should be always a three digit number.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /l %%h in (000,001,350) do (
    @ECHO Value is %%h
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String processing in windows batch files: How to pad value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398545/string-processing-in-windows-batch-files-how-to-pad-value-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four solutions which can be all seen in batch code below:

```
@echo off
set "Number=0"
:NumberIncrement
set "Value=00%Number%"
echo Value is %Value:~-3%
set /A Number+=1
if not %Number% == 351 goto NumberIncrement

echo ===============================================================================

rem Above solution optimized by counting from 1000 to 1350.
set "Value=1000"
:ValueIncrement
echo Value is %Value:~-3%
set /A Value+=1
if not %Value% == 1351 goto ValueIncrement

echo ===============================================================================

rem Delayed environment variable expansion is needed for loop solutions.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%I in (0,1,350) do (
    set "Value=00%%I"
    echo Value is !Value:~-3!
)

echo ===============================================================================

rem Above solution a bit optimized by counting from 1000 to 1350 and
rem using operator & to specify two commands on a single command line.

for /L %%I in (1000,1,1350) do set "Value=%%I" & echo Value is !Value:~-3!

endlocal
```

The environment variable `Value` is defined with two leading zeros and appended as string the current number (solution 1 and 3). Alternatively the value counting is done from 1000 to 1350 (solution 2 and 4). Only the last 3 characters are output from string value of environment variable `Value` resulting in output of `000` to `350`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thanks @Mofi . I got my answer form your solution 3 and 4.