# CMD: Can't add 1 to 08 using += operator

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using CMD commands to work on some variables. I can add 1 to a variable but if that variable is 08 or 09, the result comes out to be 1,rather than 9 or 10. Here's the code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set day=08
echo Day:%day%
set /a day+=1
echo Day:% day%
```

This works for numbers 1-7, and after 10. I need to add a leading zero to digits less than 10 because otherwise somehow the variable is not written to a text file (which I perform later) despite showing the correct value in other parts of the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String processing in windows batch files: How to pad value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398545/string-processing-in-windows-batch-files-how-to-pad-value-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: I bet if you read the help file for the SET command you would see why you can't do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help for command **SET** can be read by running in a command prompt window `set /?`. It explains that numbers with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers, see function [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) with **base** being `0` (automatic detection) as used internally by Windows command interpreter.

`08` and `09` are invalid in octal number system and are therefore interpreted with value `0`.

One solution for this case is using first a string concatenation during preprocessing state to change the string `08` to `108` and subtract `99` from `108` converted to an integer number to get `08` and `09` as well as `01` to `31` incremented by `1`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "day=08"
echo Day: %day%
set /A day=1%day% - 99
echo Day: %day%
endlocal
```

The output of above batch file is:

```
Day: 08
Day: 9
```

Delayed environment variable expansion is not needed here and in general not needed at all in an arithmetic expression as also explained by help of command **SET**. There are of course exceptions like a string concatenation must be done first before executing the arithmetic expression within a command block on which the environment variable was defined or modified before in the command block. But those use cases are really rare.

When the result should be again with a leading `0` for numbers with less than two digits, it is best not subtracting `99`, but adding `1` and assign to the environment variable in next step just the last two digits from the string with always 3 digits after evaluation of arithmetic expression.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "day=08"
echo Day: %day%
set /A day=1%day% + 1
set "day=%day:~-2%"
echo Day: %day%
endlocal
```

The output of above batch file is:

```
Day: 08
Day: 09
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a nice workaround. Fortunately I managed to bypass the requirement of adding 0 as I discovered that a single digit can be saved to a text file using another format of echo

Answer (score 0):

```
Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless
prefixed by 0x for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers.
So 0x12 is the same as 18 is the same as 022. Please note that the octal
notation can be confusing: 08 and 09 are not valid numbers because 8 and
9 are not valid octal digits.
```

From `set /?`.