# Strange arithmetic issue in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been experiencing a very strange issue in CMD and I can't for the life of me figure out why it's doing this!

I'm performing arithmetic on some dates and subtracting one from the month and it was going just fine until I got to the numbers 8 & 9! Because I'm dealing with dates, I'm adding a preceding 0 for any value less than 10, which makes 8 become 08.

I input the following into the cmd (keep in mind that for values 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07 & 10, the below code will work just fine):

```
set z=08
set /a z-1
```

somehow this code returns an answer of -1 instead of the expected 7!

yet if I do:

```
set z=8
set /a z-1
```

This code returns 7 which is what I would expect.

What on earth is going on here?

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: The cold clammy hands of DEC (Digital Equipment Corporation) strike again.  A leading zero specifies an octal value (base 8 instead of base 10).  So 8 and 9 are not valid literals.

Comment: Sorry aschipfl I'm a major newb, but I'll remember that knowledge going forward so thank!

Comment: If you always have two-digit numbers, there is a nice work-around: prepend a `1`, then do the subtraction, then remove the leading `1`, like this: `set /A (1%z%-1)%%100` (`1%z%` prepends a `1`, `-1` is the subtraction, and `%%100` removes the `1` by modulus operation)

Comment: Hans thanks so much for that answer, I don't know how on earth I'd ever have come to that conclusion

Comment: @aschipfl Ahhh that's a really good one, thanks for this!

Comment: @HansPassant is it really DEC's fault for choosing a leading zero to specify octal? I thought it was Dennis Ritchie, inventor of the C language.

Comment: Dennis used a PDP-8 and PDP-11 to develop the C language;  DEC machines, those eggs went before the chicken.

Comment: And just so we are clear, everything you are testing right now can only be done from the cmd prompt. If you need to assign the output of the expression to a value you must use: `set /a z-=1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMD: Can't add 1 to 08 using += operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668536/cmd-cant-add-1-to-08-using-operator) @kxk You would have just to run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the help for command __SET__ which explains that a number starting with `0` is interpreted as octal number in an arithmetic expression.