# How to create a number with N digits in Batch Script Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, maxlength, digit

I would like to create a number with N digits.

*Example;*

`myVar=543` and I would like it with 6 digits so myVar will be `000543`

```
myVar=44345 will be 044345
myVar=1 will be 0000001
...
```

I do that with Batch, so just with Windows Batch commands.

Comment: Is that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398545/string-processing-in-windows-batch-files-how-to-pad-value-with-leading-zeros working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add 6 zeros at the front of the number and then cut the last 6 characters:

```
set myVar=51
echo 1: %myVar%
set myVar=000000%myvar%
echo 2: %myVar%
set myVar=%myVar:~-6%
echo 3: %myVar%
```

Answer (score 0):

Stephan's method works. It can also be done using PowerShell formatting.

```
SET "N=123.4"
FOR /F %%n IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "([double]%N%).ToString('000000')"') DO (SET "NZ=%%n")
ECHO %NZ%
```