# How to loop batch file path to .txt command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating file path .txt files with files names that corresspond to the day of the year. Rather than having to create a .bat file with 365 lines for each day of the year is there a simpler way to loop through in daily increments?

Currently my .bat looks like this:

```
dir A2018001* /a /b /s > 2018001.txt
dir A2018002* /a /b /s > 2018002.txt
dir A2018003* /a /b /s > 2018003.txt
dir A2018004* /a /b /s > 2018004.txt
dir A2018005* /a /b /s > 2018005.txt
dir A2018006* /a /b /s > 2018006.txt
dir A2018007* /a /b /s > 2018007.txt
dir A2018008* /a /b /s > 2018008.txt
dir A2018009* /a /b /s > 2018009.txt
```

etc....

Which works fine but is there a way to avoid having 365 lines of code in the .bat with a loop?

Im very new to using `/l` but I tried this:

```
for /l %%x in (001, 1, 365) do (
    echo %x
    dir A2018001* /a /b /s > 2018001.txt
)
```

and it did not cycle through the files.

Is there a way to achieve the above code with a `for` loop going up in increments of 1 for each day so I dont have to write it out 365 times?

Comment: To keep the number of digits let the loop cycle through the whole number `for /l %%x in (2018001,1,2018365) do (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done the code almost correctly. Just need to [pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398545/string-processing-in-windows-batch-files-how-to-pad-value-with-leading-zeros) the variable with zeroes.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%x in (1,1,365) do (
    set "d=00%%x"
    set "d=!d:~-3!"
    dir "A2018!d!*" /a /b /s > "2018!d!.txt"
)
```

Comment: I seems LotPings' padding method is simpler. (and it avoids the delayedExpansion/!  classical problem). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @XouDo LotPing's solution is simpler but not quite universal. If the name will have only letters before the counter or none at all (i. e. `ABC001`) it will not work.