# Increment folder name based on partial folder name

Tags: batch-file, numbers

I have a bunch of folder which time stamped.

- 001_FDV__24-04-2020_2152
- 002_FDV__27-04-2020_2202
- 003_FDV__29-04-2020_2209
- 004_FDV__01-05-2020_2240

All the above files are located `c:\video_production`

This is the code what I have at the moment.

```
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a-%%b-%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

REM
set mydir=FDV_%mydate%_%mytime%
mkdir %mydir%
move *.* %mydir%
```

I would like to increment the folder number from the last on in `c:\video_production`. Do I would have 005, 006, 007 etc.

Thank you

Comment: What happens when the last folder created is 999?

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe 0000. 4 digits. That would be better I think.

Comment: If you might have more than 1,000 but less than 9,000, I would suggest beginning with 1000 or 1001 and counting up from there.  I often do this so I don't have to bother with padding zeros.  If you absolutely want padded zeros, then figure out how big you want to support and use that many digits from the beginning.  Meaning, if you want more than 1,000 folders but less than 10,000 then use 4 digits -- 0001, 0002 etc.  If you need more than 10,000 then 00001 etc.

Comment: If you don't know how to pad zeros: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398545/string-processing-in-windows-batch-files-how-to-pad-value-with-leading-zeros

Comment: @avery_larry You recommendations have been acknowledged and implemented. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to find the largest zero padded 3 digit number from the first 3 digits of all the folder names.

**untested**

```
rem the dir listing of folders only sorted alphabetically in reverse, the first folder listed will be the "last" one
for /f %%a in ('dir /ad /o-n /b "c:\video_production"') do (
   set "lastfolder=%%~a"
   goto :continue
)

:continue
rem At this point, lastfolder should be the "last" folder name.
rem Get the first 3 digits.  Change to 4 for 4 digits or 5 for 5 etc.
set lastnumber=%lastfolder:~0,3%

rem Now lastnumber should be the zero padded number.
rem There are a variety of ways to increment this number.
rem I prefer to remove the zero padding, increment it, and then zero pad it again.

rem There are many ways to remove the zero padding.
rem I like to manipulate the string and then use modulo to get the number.
rem We can also increment it in one statement with this method.

rem Use 10000 for 4 digits, 100000 for 5 digits, etc.
set /a nextnumber = 1%lastnumber% %% 1000 + 1

rem Now we pad it with zeros.
rem Use 000 for 4 digits, 0000 for 5 digits, etc.
set nextnumber=00%nextnumber%
rem and trim it to 3 digits.
rem use 4 for 4 digits, 5 for 5 etc.
set nextnumber=%nextnumber:~-3%

rem And you should be good to go:
set mydir=%nextnumber%_FDV_%mydate%_%mytime%
```

Hopefully it is obvious that **the folder number must be a precise number of digits**.  It is **MUCH** more complicated to have an unknown number of digits with an unknown amount of padded zeros.

Comment: Tested with 000 and 0000. Works as expected. Thank you!